# How to split text around pages?

Tags: graphics, floats, page-breaking

I have one input which has text and image.

Here text is quite lengthy which may occupy 2-3 pages. I want output like

1. some text on 1st page
2. then image on 2nd page
3. then rest of text on 3rd page.

Is it possible to do this automatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard way of doing this is embedding the image in a floating `figure` environment and specifying that it should be positioned on a dedicated float-page with the option `p`. Place this `figure` environment roughly after the batch of text after which it should appear. In my simple example, you could even put it before the text-generating `\lipsum` command. If you want to learn more about this topic, we have a great post expertly explaining float positioning in LaTeX: [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/4012)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum, mwe} % just for demo contents
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[p]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image-10x16}
    \caption{This is my image}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[1-14]
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Just a remark: In the case the figure is too small, it 1) doesn't look nicely and 2) if you still want it, changing `[p]` to `[!p]` might be necessary.